# Failing while trying to deploy Talend Agent in Pivtal Cloud FOundry

Tags: talend, cloud-foundry

I have been trying to deploy Talend Agent as app in PCF, I literally have no idea about Talend. However for PCF guy, its an java jar file for me what i got from DATA team.

I am getting no buildpack supported error. I also tried passing java buildpack by command but failed again with incompatible buildpack.

```
Error: No container can run this application. Please ensure that you've pushed a valid JVM artifact or artifacts using the -p command line argument or path manifest entry. Information about valid JVM artifacts can be found at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#additional-documentation.
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run finalize script: exit status 1
```

I was expecting this to be deployed as an App which i can access.
Do we have any one who can help me with this?

Comment: Could it be a problem related to java version ? For example if data team developed it using java 8 and you are running java 7 on your server ?

Answer (score 1):

The CF Java buildpack expects a Java jar file to have certain characteristics in order for it to know how to execute the code in the jar file. The most common characteristics are a [self-executable Spring Boot](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-spring_boot.md#spring-boot-container) app, an app containing [a Main class](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-java_main.md#java-main-container), and an app [containing Tomcat](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-tomcat.md#tomcat-container).

I don't know anything about the Talend Agent, but a typical [Java agent](https://javabeat.net/introduction-to-java-agents) jar file is not meant to be executed as a stand-alone app. An agent is meant to be installed in the JVM used to run an app, in order to instrument the JVM and/or the app. An typical agent jar file won't have any of the execution entry points recognized by the CF Java buildpack, and therefore the buildpack will reject it with an error message similar to the one you show.

The CF Java buildpack does understand how to install several specific agents (listed under [Standard Frameworks in the buildpack docs](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#additional-documentation)) into the JVM when an app is deployed. The Talend Agent is not currently in this list. If it is in fact a typical Java agent jar file, you would have to modify the Java buildpack to add support for it.